# TextView set and get text size differs

Tags: java, android, textview, text-size

I get the text Size from the TextView and store in DB and

Later I am trying to set the value back. But I am getting different size on the display.

Whats the correct way to do this ?

|*| Get Text Size from Text View Store in DB :

```
int txtSyzVar = namTextViewVar.getTextSize();
```

|*| Later Fetch Back and Set :

```
namTextViewVar.setTextSize(txtSyzVar);
```

Also tried

```
namTextViewVar.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, txtSyzVar);
namTextViewVar.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, txtSyzVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GridLayout on xml for aligned elements.

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".GridXMLActivity" >
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: In this case 2x2.